# Different results using leastsq and least_square (with lm) with Scipy 1.0.0?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I wonder if it is expected that Scipy's 1.0.0 leastsq and least_square (with lm) optimizers produce different results. The following code demonstrates that problem for me. (It's fitting Steinhart-Hart parameters.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

#r = np.array([10030.217595+100, 3065.807003+30, 207.740077+2, 115.510462+1])
r = np.array([10030.217595, 3065.807003, 207.740077, 115.510462])
t = np.array([273.15, 298.17, 373.17, 394.29])

def steinhart(r, a, b, c):
    "NTC : steinhart(x, a, b, c)"
    return 1.0/( a + b*np.log(r) + c*(np.log(r))**3 )

def residual(p, r, t):
    return t - steinhart(r, *p)

p0 = [1e-1, 1e-2, 1e-4]

# This works (uses lm)
popt, xx = optimize.leastsq(residual, p0, args=(r, t))
print("leastsq:        "+str(popt))

# Doesn't work, but should be the same as above
# Now it works!!! ???
popt2 = optimize.least_squares(residual, p0, args=(r, t), method='lm')
print("least_squares:  "+str(popt2))

# Original parameter to generate the data, for comparison
p_org = [1.4e-3, 2.37e-4, 9.9e-8]
print("Correct answer: "+str(p_org))
```

When running this, leastsq gets it right, while least_squares does not converge. I get `message: 'The maximum number of function evaluations is exceeded.'`.

Am I doing something wrong? The test works fine with older Scipy 0.17.0 or 0.19.1.

P.S.: The values that I'm fitting were generated using the `p_org` parameters and the fit function could get a perfect fit. If I add some noise by changing the values a little (just use the commented line 5 to define r) least_squares does converge. Still, this should not happen, or should it?

Comment: Both work fine for me, same results. SciPy 0.19.1, Python 3.6.3. Maybe your SciPy is old?

Comment: Turns out my SciPy is new, version 1.0.0. Too new? The testcase was written and tested with Python 3.6.3 and Scipy installed via pip3 (on Cygin32). I ran my test on a different machine under Ubuntu with stock SciPy 0.17.0 and there it works fine. I'll update the question.

Comment: Works for me on Mac OSX SciPy 1.0.0 Python 3.6.1.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu, Scipy 1.0.0, Python 3.6.2